# How to replace substring with php whatever it is lower or upper characters

Tags: php

I need to replace sub-string whatever this string uppercase or lower case

```
$sub = "STR";
$newsub="All-";
$str="Strstring";
$newstr=str_replace($sub,$rep,$str);
```

Comment: use str_ireplace inplace of str_replace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str_ireplace` function of PHP as

```
$sub = "STR";
$newsub="All-";
$str="Strstring";
$newstr=str_ireplace($sub,$newsub,$str);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/383609)

Comment: You have an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` also -

```
$sub = array('/STR/i');
$newsub="All-";
$str="Strstring";
echo $newstr=preg_replace($sub, $newsub, $str);
```

**Output**

```
All-All-ing
```